# Running JSHint with HTML and getting errors

Tags: javascript, jshint

I'm a newbie to JSHint and trying to run it to validate my Javascript. I have node.js installed and when i try to run JSHint i get the error below.

```
C:\Users\574839\Desktop\testscr.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { <!DOCTYPE html>
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:513:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
at startup (node.js:160:18)
at node.js:456:3
```

I have a .jshintrc file with the following options:

```
{
 "bitwise": true,
 "camelcase": true,
 "curly": true,
 "eqeqeq": true,
 "es3": false,
 "forin": true,
 "freeze": true,
 "immed": true,
 "indent": 4,
 "latedef": "nofunc",
    "newcap": true,
    "noarg": true,
  "noempty": true,
  "nonbsp": true,
  "nonew": true,
 "plusplus": false,
 "quotmark": "single",
 "undef": true,
 "unused": false,
 "strict": false,
 "maxparams": 10,
 "maxdepth": 5,
 "maxstatements": 40,
 "maxcomplexity": 8,
 "maxlen": 120,
 "asi": false,
 "boss": false,
 "debug": false,
 "eqnull": true,
 "esnext": false,
 "evil": false,
 "expr": false,
 "funcscope": false,
 "globalstrict": false,
 "iterator": false,
 "lastsemic": false,
 "laxbreak": false,
 "laxcomma": false,
 "loopfunc": true,
 "maxerr": false,
 "moz": false,
 "multistr": false,
 "notypeof": false,
 "proto": false,
 "scripturl": false,
 "shadow": false,
 "sub": true,
 "supernew": false,
 "validthis": false,
 "noyield": false,
 "browser": true,
 "node": true,
 "globals": {
     "angular": false,
   "$": false
  }
}
```

Can someone please advise why I get the error?

my JS code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>What Can JavaScript Do?</h1>

<p id="demo">JavaScript can change HTML content.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML='Hello JavaScript!'">Click Me!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an HTML file and not a JavaScript file. But luckily JSHint can work on the javascript from HTML files if you pass the --extract option to it.

From the [documentation](http://jshint.com/docs/cli/):

> `--extract=[auto|always|never]`
>
> Tells JSHint to extract JavaScript from HTML files before linting:

```
tmp ☭ cat test.html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello, World!</title>
    <script>
      function hello() {
        return "Hello, World!";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
    <script>
      console.log(hello())
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

tmp ☭ jshint --extract=auto test.html
test.html: line 13, col 27, Missing semicolon.

1 error
```

> If you set it to *always* JSHint will always attempt to extract
>   JavaScript. And if you set it to *auto* it will make an attempt only
>   if file looks like it's an HTML file.

In the mean time, it still doesn't recognize the javascript in HTML attribute event handlers like onclick such as this case, which is a bad practice. If you really want to have your Javascript in HTML you have put it in script tags such as the following:

**testscr.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

    <h1>What Can JavaScript Do?</h1>

    <p id="demo">JavaScript can change HTML content.</p>

    <button type="button" onclick="sayHello()">Click Me!</button>
    <script>
      function sayHello() {
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML='Hello JavaScript!';
      }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also it looks like you're passing it to node, like `node testscr.js`, but what you should be doing is to pass it to jshint: `jshint --extract=always testscr.js`

Comment: Is there a way to tell JSHint to extract JS from HTML and test only the JS?

Comment: Thanks Farid! One last question. Does it produce like a log file besides showing the errors/warnings in the console? I'm not sure where to look for the output of a test.

Comment: Scratch what I said, have a look at the answer again. I updated it. If you want the output to be in a file, just pipe it: `jshint --extract=always testscr.js > output.txt`

Comment: Where do set the flag to only check js files in the .jshint file?

Comment: @Flash It's not possible right now. There's an [issue](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/1966) filed for it though, so you can track it there.