# SublimeLinter-jshint: Errors when script in <body> tags

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, jslint, jshint, sublimelinter

I seem to be having a problem with SublimeLinter-jshint and I couldn't find what I was looking for in the JSLint docs. At first, I thought it was a problem specifically with *"Missing semicolon"* (after an opening curly brace) but as I tried to ignore the issue and carry on with coding, more and more other errors kept popping up.

I am currently working through a JS tutorial and have all my scripts inline. I did notice that when I moved all of my JavaScript into a script in the head of the HTML file, all of the warnings disappeared (I tested it by intentionally breaking some of the code to see if it was still working, and all was fine).

What is it I'm doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
    <title>Object Oriented JS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*jslint evil: true */

        function Person(name, street){
            this.name = name;
            this.street = street;
            this.info = function(){
                return "My name is " + this.name + " and I live on " + this.street;
            };
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function Mammal(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.getInfo = function(){
        return "The mammals name is " + this.name;
    };
}

Mammal.prototype.sound = "Grrr";

Mammal.prototype.makeSound = function() {
    return this.name + " says " + this.sound;
};

var grover = new Mammal("Grover");

document.write(grover.makeSound() + "<br />");

for(var prop in grover){
    document.write(prop + " : " + grover[prop] + "<br />");
}


</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Just to add, everything is loading absolutely fine in the browser so I'm pretty sure these are false warnings.

Comment: Is it complaining about `document.write`? You should read about modern ways of DOM manipulation.

Comment: It was, that is until I suppressed it. It is currently complaining of _Missing semicolon_ (which it is claiming should go after function Mammal(name) for instance), _Expecting an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression_, _Creating global 'for' variable. Should be 'for (var varprop...'_. I found it strange that moving it into the head totally got rid of all of the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to overcome this with jshint's `--extract` argument, which is not yet supported in `.jshintrc` file. I added the following lines to my `SublimeLinter.sublime-settings` and it fixed it for me:

```
"linters": {
    "jshint": {"args": ["--extract=always"]}
}
```

Refs:

- SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38143402/484127
- Docs: https://jshint.com/docs/cli/
- Feature request: https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/1966